# What's the proper name for "annular potentiometer"?

Tags: motor, components, potentiometer, trimmer

I'm looking for a potentiometer without the shaft. It should be like a ring, in annular shape, so it can be mounted on an existing shaft.

I don't find anything, but I'm afraid I'm not using the proper English word to describe such a component.

Comment: i have seen the layers referred to as `wafer` and `element` ... but no idea about the name of an assembly that you add to an existing potentiometer

Comment: Not to an existing potentiometer, but to an existing shaft, i.e. of a motor

Comment: rotary position sensor ...... something like this https://www.vishay.com/sensors/list/product-54003/    and this  https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/sensor/rotaryposition/sv01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try image searches for

- [coaxial+potentiometer](https://www.google.ie/search?q=coaxial+potentiometer).
- [concentric+potentiometer](https://www.google.ie/search?q=concentric+potentiometer&oq=concentric+potentiometer).
- [hollow+shaft+potentiometer](https://www.google.ie/search?q=hollow+shaft+potentiometer&oq=hollow+shaft+potentiometer).

[image]

The first two searches give you all the dual shaft pots as found on audio and analog oscilloscopes. The latter are the most unusual.